# Error: You cannot use gems with Shopify CLI

Tags: ruby, rubygems, shopify

I am new to Shopify theme development. Currently following the tutorial by Shopify. Everything was going smoothly but I am getting the following error every time I run "Shopify theme serve":

```
[Note] You cannot use gems with Shopify CLI.
[LoadError] cannot load such file -- wdm
       They are disabled.
       Please don't modify the CLI locally.
       If you would like to contribute to the CLI project, please refer to
       https://github.com/Shopify/shopify-cli/blob/main/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md

  Please add the following to your Gemfile to avoid polling for changes:
    gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?
X You are not authorized to edit themes on banana-man-co.myshopify.com.
Make sure you are a user of that store, and allowed to edit themes.
```

Also, I know it says I am not authorized to edit themes but I am pretty sure that I am logged in as the admin. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try adding `gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if Gem.win_platform?` in your Gemfile?
Also, if you are running windows, Ruby does not play nice with it.

Comment: I am running windows. I will try adding that. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run

> gem install wdm

on the command prompt.

Then you won't see this issue but still see

```
X You are not authorized to edit themes on banana-man-co.myshopify.com.
Make sure you are a user of that store, and allowed to edit themes.
```

Follow **Caution** section on https://shopify.dev/themes/tools/cli/getting-started.

Answer (score 3):

For arch linux where shopify-cli is installed using:

```
gem install shopify-cli
```

You need to install the Bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

See more details in [archlinux ruby wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Ruby#Setup). Hope this helps someone.